# Magento 1.94 image upload - exif missing

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, image-upload

After upgrade to 1.94 I realized that image upload is removing all Exif data from uploaded images. I tried to search for any '->stripImage()' string in the project but no success.

Comment: explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

The reason Magento strips metadata is because it poses a security risk, so I would highly recommend against disabling it, but I'll still explain below how you would do it.

### How to disable image reprocessing

Instead of just removing EXIF data, as of `Magento 1.9.3.3` it rebuilds the entire image into a new file. The logic for this can be found within the following function `\Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image::validate`

As of `Magento 1.9.3.6` you will also notice in the `validate` function there is an early return statement that checks `general/reprocess_images/active`.

You can set this to a falsely value through an XML config file, which would remove this additional security measure.

### Additional Note

If you really wanted to have the metadata on the new image, I would recommend extending the `validate` function. Reading the meta data from the old file with `exif_read_data`, applying some manual processing/sanitization on the results and setting it on the new image.